# HTTPS calls made from angular application

Tags: angular, https

How can I make HTTPS request from angular app to c# controller. Is it possible at all?
How do I provide certificate & public / private key along with C# request.

```
e.g 
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'https://ourlady:4000'
};
const baseUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/accounts`;
register(account: Account) {
        return this.http.post(`${baseUrl}/register`, account);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make https calls with angular HttpClient - just start your request with https://
Everything else, including check for certificate, is done by browser

Comment: I am getting `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error. I have certificate properly installed as my request from browser to angular is processed correctly. Its when I try to communicate from angular to c# process through `"https://192.168.0.19:4000"' when it fails.

Comment: Try run
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust